Understand a specific way of initialising a list in C#
I am using Visual Studio Code to learn C# and I wrote the following code:
string value = "abc123";
List<char> valueList = value.ToList<char>();

I understand this first piece of code perfectly.
However, VS Code suggested another syntax for the second line of code, giving :
string value = "abc123";
List<char> valueList = [.. value];

I have been looking for more information about this syntax, but I have not been able to find anything about it.
I want to understand the syntax [.. value].
What is the name of such a structure and how does it work ?

That's a collection expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions

^^ Specifically the spread element

This is new syntax which had its roots in JavaScript Spead Operators. cript
